# Cortex M4 stacking and unstacking with a diferent stack pointer

Tags: stack, cortex-m, interrupted-exception, stack-pointer, stacking-context

It is possible to achieve this in a cortex-m4? What i mean is having PSP only on that intervals, and all the rest MSP when there is an interrupt?

The objective is just to do the stacking and unstacking on a diferent memory location!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On exception entry the context is saved to the stack which was currently in use by the processor at the time.  If you were running in main context then this could be MSP or PSP depending on the SPSEL bit of the CONTROL special register.

During exception handling only the MSP is used.

When returning from a nested interrupt to an outer interrupt then the context is restored from the MSP.

When returning from an exception to main context you can choose which stack context is restored from by setting bit[2] of the special return address written to the program counter.

You can of course change where either or both of the stack pointers point while you are in interrupt context.

See section B1.5 of the [ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f8fef3af86e16515cdbf816) for full details.

Comment: Yes thank you for your answer, but I wanted to know if it is possible to on exception entry save the context to a different stack than the one that was currently in use by the processor at the time. And then restore to that same different stack that the context was saved before!

Comment: As I said, on exception entry the context is saved to the stack which was currently in use by the processor at the time.  This is done by hardware and cannot be changed.